# making it so you can call composer from any directory

Tags: php, linux, composer-php

I put composer.phar in /usr/bin and I then created /usr/bin/composer with `php /usr/bin/composer.phar $@` and then when I try to run `composer` I get the following:

```
No command 'composer' found, did you mean:
 Command 'compose' from package 'mime-support' (main)
composer: command not found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Seeing as you put the file `composer.phar` in your bin directory, that's the command you'll have to run: `composer.phar`, not `composer`. Either create an alias in your bashrc file, or try `mv /usr/bin/composer.phar /usr/bin/composer`, and you should be good. The alias would be the easiest: `alias composer="composer.phar"`, job done

Comment: Note that the Linux FHS recommends non-package-manager executables to be placed in `/usr/local/bin/` instead of `/usr/bin/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use symlink:

```
ln -s ~/composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
chmod +x ~/composer.phar
```

Comment: You could also rename the file from `composer.phar` to `composer` and add the x bit to make it executable. Problem with placing the file anywhere in `/usr/bin`: Only root can run self-update.

Comment: Or `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin` in .bashrc and use `~/.local/bin` instead of `/usr/bin` if you don't have root.